# How to access to dates from a database in dynamic events

Tags: anylogic

I would like to use my different dates of my database time arrival in my dynamic event. How get I access to it. To use values or different times isn't a problem but I dont't understand how I can use my different dates from my database in my dynamic event. 
I have different amounts of pallets which should get released to the certain times of my dbase. 
For the pallets I use the parameters with the different amounts, the only problem is that I don't know how I can implement the dbase into the dynamic event. 
For example at 7 am 30 pallets (parameter1) should leave the pallet rack. 
[dbase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dR0NT.png)

Answer (score 0):

assuming your dynamic event is called MyDynamicEvent, your database is called my_db and your column with the dates is called dates, then on main startup you can do the following:

```
List< Date > dates=selectFrom(my_db).list(my_db.dates);
for(Date date : dates ) {
    Date today=date();
    long diff = date.getTime() - today.getTime();
    create_MyDynamicEvent(diff,MILLISECOND);
}
```

This will create all the dynamic events you need based on your database. In your dynamic event you can generate the code necessary to do whatever you want with your pallets

Comment: Another question: Do I write the information about my pallets into the dynamic event itself or into the function you wrote (after the time, millisecond)? And: Is it possible to use this function for different dynamic events and process flows? Or could I copy the function and then use it for different dynamic events after I rename the components of the function.

Comment: Because I need different databases and dynamic events

Comment: you asked how to trigger dynamic events at the dates defined on your database... if you want something else, then you will have to ask a different quesiotn... i don't see why you would use this inside a dynamic event...

Comment: Ah okay you are right. So for my problem I don‘t need a dynamic event „block“ separatly. So I can write my pallet numbers/ the parameters directly into the function you gave me? I thought I also need the dynamic event in addition to the function you wrote.